# INVALID_SESSION_ID in getting leads from salesforce through Rest api php

Tags: php, rest, session, salesforce, invalidation

Hi i need to get the leads from the salesforce through rest api for this i have done so far a successful oauth through rest api and i got a following response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [access_token] => 1111xxxxxxxx44444444444444
    [instance_url] => https://eu7.salesforce.com
    [id] => https://login.salesforce.com/id/000000000
    [token_type] => Bearer
    [issued_at] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
    [signature] => xxxxxxxxxxxx
)
```

after that for getting contact leads i am using the below code

```
$email = 'test_@gmail.com';
$query = 'SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead';
if($email != null){
$query .= sprintf("WHERE Email ='%s'", $email);
}
$url = $instance_url. '/services/data/v33.0/query?q=' . urlencode($query);
$paramsnew = "access_token=$access_token";
$urlcurl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $paramsnew);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$urljson_response = curl_exec($urlcurl);
echo $urljson_response; 
curl_close($urlcurl);
```

but in response i am getting below

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

Please suggest how can i fix this.

Comment: sessions (bearer tokens) only last 20 min before require new validation. also whats the path between the object and $access_token

Answer (score 1):

Finally i fixed it by using the below code.

```
$firstname = 'rohit';
$query = 'SELECT FirstName , LastName ,Id, Email FROM Lead ';
if($firstname != null){
$query .= sprintf("WHERE FirstName ='%s'", $firstname);
}
$url = $instance_url. '/services/data/v33.0/query?q=' . urlencode($query);
$paramsnew = "access_token=$access_token";
$urlcurl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$urljson_response = curl_exec($urlcurl);
print_r(json_decode($urljson_response)); 
curl_close($urlcurl);
```

we need to pass the access token like

```
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
```

and we need to use get method of curl.

```
curl_setopt($urlcurl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 more example of the rest client response for new API version.

[image]